# Cannot get child hook to receive state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to be able to pass the current user from my `Comment` component to my `CommentList` component

```
class Comment extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Header
                    rounded
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                        position: 'relative',
                    }}
                >
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', right: '43%', top: '50%'}}>
                        <Icon name='chevron-left' size={10} color='#006FFF' style={{top: '6%'}}/>
                        <NativeText
                            onPress={() => this.props.history.push('/')}
                            style ={{color: '#006FFF', fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular'}}
                        >
                            Back
                        </NativeText>
                    </View>
                </Header>
                <View
                    style={{paddingLeft: '2%', paddingTop: '2%'}}
                >
                    <CommentList

                        options={this.props.location.state.comments}
                        currentUser={this.props.location.state.currentUser}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Comment)

const CommentList = (options, currentUser) => {
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)
    const [parentId, changeParentId] = useState('')
    const [commentInput, changeComment] = useState('')

    return ( 
      <View>{console.log(currentUser)}
          {options.options.map(option => (
              <View>
                <NativeText
                    style={{fontSize: 12, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular'}}
                >
                    {option.content}
                </NativeText>
                <Icon
                    name='reply'
                    size={12}
                    onPress={() => {
                        setModalVisible(true)
                        changeParentId(option._id)
                    }}
                />
                { 
                <View
                    style={{left: '10%'}}
                >
                    <CommentList
                        options={option.reply}
                    />
                </View>
                }
            </View>
          ))}
      </View>
    )
}
```

When I try to pass it through `currentUser`, it returns an empty object; `options` does show up in `CommentList`.

Comment: How are you using the Comment component and how are you passing props to it?

Comment: I’m passing it through react router. I know that the information exists in `this.props.location.state.currentUser` And has the current user info. It just doesn’t exist in CommentList.

Comment: Is currentUser is asynchronous data??

Comment: You should change your definition of `CommentList` to something like `const CommentList = ({options, currentUser}) => {`

Comment: @schoenbl Have you tried logging out `this.props.location.state.currentUser` at the top of the Comment render method?

Comment: @schoenbl Also, when you call CommentList component inside itself you are not passing the currentUser prop.

Comment: @jack Yes, I receive the current user data in the Comment render. Correct, I am not calling it, but I should be able to see currentUser one time before recursion maps over itself.

Comment: @schoenbl Looks like you are missing the object destructuring  syntax in CommentList, it should be `const CommentList = ({options, currentUser}) => `

Comment: @schoenbl Or you could do `const CommentList = (props) => ` and access current user with `props.currentUser` inside CommentList.

Comment: @jack Does it make sense though that I can receive options with the current structure despite this?

Comment: @schoenbl You have `options.options.map` in your code because options is actually props.

Comment: @schoenbl Log out options and you will see it has both options and currentUser as properties because it is actually the props object.

Comment: @Jack You're right. If you submit that response as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @schoenbl Awesome, will do! You’re very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the object destructuring syntax  for CommentList. It should be as follows:

```
const CommentList = ({ options, currentUser }) => {
    // component content
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The props you pass to functional component are consolidated into an object. So you need to **destructure** the values.

Or,

```css
    const CommentList = (props) => {
       //props.options //props.currentUser
     }
```